# Include react generated HTML/JS files from composite gradle build

Tags: java, reactjs, gradle

I have 2 Gradle projects that I want to link together. The first project has a standard Spring Boot app, and I want to link it with a ReactJS project that I've added a "build.gradle" file to.

I want to include the files generated into the "build/" directory of the ReactJS project into the "META-INF/resources" directory of the Spring Boot project.

These are my gradle.build files:

Spring Boot Gradle project:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.5.2.RELEASE'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'

group = "com.myproject"
version = "1.0"

bootRun {
    systemProperties = System.properties
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    compile("com.myproject:myproject-ui:1.0")
}
```

ReactJS Gradle project:

```
plugins {
    id "com.moowork.node" version "1.1.1"
}

node {
    download = true
}

apply plugin: 'java'

group = "com.myproject"
version = "1.0"

buildDir = 'dist'

task webjar(type: Jar, dependsOn: 'jar') {
    from(fileTree('build')) {
        into 'META-INF/resources'
    }
}

build.dependsOn(webjar)
build.dependsOn(npm_run_build)

clean {
    delete 'dist'
    delete 'build'
}
```

Assume I've setup the "settings.gradle" files correctly such that it is a composite build, because that doesn't seem to cause issues.

When I run the "build" task for the ReactJS project, the "build/" directory is successfully generated, but I doesn't seem to be included by the Spring Boot project anywhere. How can I include the generated HTML/JS files such that they show up when I run the "bootRun" task of the Spring Boot project.

Answer (score 0):

Typically you'd use a [Configuration](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.Configuration.html) for this

`reactjs/build.gradle`

```
configurations {
    wj
}
task webjar(type: Jar) { ... }
dependencies {
    wj files(webjar)
}
```

`springboot/build.gradle`

```
configurations {
    wj
}
dependencies {
    wj project(path: ':reactjs', configuration: 'wj')
}
war {
    with copySpec {
        from zipTree(configurations.wj.singleFile)
        into 'META-INF/resources'
    }
}
```